# Assisting a user using VNC

Tags: windows, vnc, vncserver, realvnc, vnc-viewer

I'm trying to help a friend with their computer remotely.

He has a version of VNC, I'm not sure which one, so I downloaded and installed the **VNC Viewer** and **Listening Viewer**.

I ask my friend for his IP address and port number, and he tells me that every time he's used it, the person giving him assistance (remotely controlling his computer) gave him some kind of number.  I should note that my friend is not tech savy, and it may have been an IP address, but I'm not sure.

What kind of number would the user be looking for?  Does this indicate his version of VNC, Does that even matter?

I am completly forign to VNC and don't know where to begin looking for an answer myself, and (for whatever reason) I can't ask my friend to figure out what version of VNC he is using.

Comment: Use something like teamviewer.com, much easier

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the person giving previously assistance to your friend use teamviewer, not vnc.

Comment: My friend knows the name of the program he clicked on... it was definitely VNC.

Comment: Maybe he is asking your ip to add it to the allowed ips in the firewall?

Comment: What does your friend with that number? knowing it will help :-)

Comment: I don't think so... I would imagine the program has a path through the firewall..., so that each connection wouldn't need a new exception.